# Set up responsive sketched borders using css

Tags: html, css

I have created a code for setting up sketch style borders over image.
Which can be seen below:

```js
jQuery('.border').click(function(){
  jQuery('.border').toggleClass('resize');  
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.border {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: all 2s;
  background-image: url(https://nosycrow.com/wp-content/themes/nosy-crow/images/borders/black-400-sides.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-position: 0 0;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.border .padding::before, .border .padding::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background: url(https://nosycrow.com/wp-content/themes/nosy-crow/images/borders/black-400.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  z-index: 50;
  padding-bottom: 5.4%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.border .padding::before {
  top: 0px;
}
.border .padding::after {
  bottom: 0px;
  background-position: 0px 100%;
}

.border.resize {
  width: 500px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="border">
  <div class="padding">
      <img src="https://nosycrow.com/wp-content/uploads/imported-books/Spectre-Collectors-Too-Ghoul-For-School-312087-3-593x911.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

But the issue is, the box is not accurately responsive. To test it out, I have added a little jquery script so when you click on the image, the image resizes. And you can see when the image is bigger, the borders doesn't look aligned properly.

I know in my solution, to fix this I have to add media queries so the borders on top and borders can be adjusted in media queries. But is there any better solution then that?

Comment: You can modify border properties using jquery when screen size is changed, so you can add some margin depending on the resize (or checking for window size) it must do the trick. $( window ).resize(function() {
  $('border').css('/*modify something*/');
});

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed using different solution. Kind of old school. I used 3 images, horizontal line, vertical line and corner and used them to set up in their position using different divs. Can be seen here

```js
jQuery('.sketchy-box').click(function(){
  jQuery('.sketchy-box').toggleClass('resize');  
});
```

```css
.sketchy-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: all 1s;
}
.sketchy-box .bdt {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 5px;
  background: url("http://aslamdoctor.com/taskapp/horizontal-stroke@4x-100.svg") left top repeat-x;
}
.sketchy-box .bdb {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 5px;
  background: url("http://aslamdoctor.com/taskapp/horizontal-stroke@4x-100.svg") left top repeat-x;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.sketchy-box .bdl {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 5px;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  background: url("http://aslamdoctor.com/taskapp/vertical-stroke@4x-100.svg") left top repeat-y;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.sketchy-box .bdr {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 5px;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  background: url("http://aslamdoctor.com/taskapp/vertical-stroke@4x-100.svg") left top repeat-y;
}
.sketchy-box .corner {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  background: url("http://aslamdoctor.com/taskapp/corner-stroke@4x-100.svg") left top no-repeat;
}
.sketchy-box .ctl {
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
.sketchy-box .ctr {
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.sketchy-box .cbl {
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.sketchy-box .cbr {
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.sketchy-box img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.sketchy-box.resize {
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sketchy-box">
  <div class="bdl"></div>
  <div class="bdr"></div>
  <div class="bdt"></div>
  <div class="bdb"></div>
  <div class="corner ctl"></div>
  <div class="corner ctr"></div>
  <div class="corner cbl"></div>
  <div class="corner cbr"></div>
  <img src="https://nosycrow.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/BooksAlways_26-27-593x320.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```